# Segmented Control Container View and UITableViews

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have a View controller with a segmented control in the navigation bar with 3 sections. All three sections will show the exact same kind of cells but the data will change. Is it more efficient to have 3 containers and hide/show them to match what data should be on screen, or should reload the table with different data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be a lot more efficient to reload table with different data.

You can do something like that for each delegate method :

> Swift version

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        return favoris.count
    } else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        return somethingElse.count
    } else {
        return somethingElse.count
    }
}
```

> Objective C version

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        return [favoris count];
    else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
        return [somethingElse count];
    else 
        return [somethingElse count];
}
```

**An other way to do would be to just change your source array regarding segmentedControl index, which will avoid you all if statements.**

I'm using this kind of feature in some projects and I can ensure that performances are good.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Sorry I think I've been down-voted because I provided Objective-C version, so I edited with Swift version.